# AWQL - how can i use a regular expressions or something similar?

Tags: regex, google-ads-api

I am querying the adwords api via the following AWQL-Query (which works fine):

```
SELECT AccountDescriptiveName, CampaignId, CampaignName, AdGroupId, AdGroupName, KeywordText, KeywordMatchType,  MaxCpc, Impressions, Clicks, Cost, Conversions, ConversionsManyPerClick, ConversionValue  
FROM KEYWORDS_PERFORMANCE_REPORT    
WHERE CampaignStatus IN ['ACTIVE', 'PAUSED']
  AND AdGroupStatus IN ['ENABLED', 'PAUSED']
  AND Status IN ['ACTIVE', 'PAUSED']
  AND AdNetworkType1 IN ['SEARCH'] AND Impressions > 0 
DURING 20140501,20140531
```

Now i want to exclude some campaigns:
we have a convention for our new campaigns that the campaign name begins with three numbers followed by an underscore, eg. "100_brand_all"
So i want to get only these new campaigns..

I tried lots of different variations for STARTS_WITH but only exact strings are working - but i need a pattern to match!

I already read https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/awql?hl=en and following its content it should be possible to use a WHERE expression like this:

```
CampaignName STARTS_WITH ['0','1','2','3']
```

But that doesn't work!

Any other ideas how i can achieve this?

Comment: I wouldn't use or depend on advance features of AWQL. There are many bugs in the API. When I have to fetch a lot of values, I cycle through the campaigns individually to break up the results, and accumulate them (or use a callback). I would loop through the campaigns, and use your local language to perform the regular expression and skip the ones that you do not want.

Answer (score 0):

Well, why don't you run a campaign performance report first, then process that ( get the campaign ids you want or don't want) the use those in the "CampaignId IN [campaign ids here] . or CampaignID NOT_IN [campaign ids]